# Direction of current flow?

Tags: current, electromagnetism

From the following diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Are the current directions correct? Based on where the terminals are connected on both conductors?

Comment: Is this a cube or a very thin but wide stripe?

Comment: It's thickness is a 1mm, it's width is also 1mm, it's height for the square cube is 1mm too, however for the rectangle has a height that is 0.5mm or possible less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the current will spread out across the whole conductor, there will be more curent in the centre but as the path that skirts the edges is only a litttle longer the current density there will be only a little lower

Comment: If one we're to apply Lorentz force(if placed in a magnetic field), this direction of current as diagrammed is considered correct? So that the force would be perpendicular to it, acting at an angle?

Comment: no, if you are consdering the magnetic field it produces the current will prefer the loop with the largest area. but most conductors are resistors and that has the effect of spreading the current out.

Comment: I mean the other way around, assuming current is applied from the power supply, and the conductor is placed in a magnetic field, there is a Lorentz force perpendicular to the current flow as diagramed: http://i.imgur.com/KIKzG5V.png?1 and http://i.imgur.com/a8myJWK.png?1 ... would the current directions be valid as diagrammed? And the forces?

Comment: Are you asking about the hall effect?

Answer (score 1):

The general direction, yes. The actual current will fill up a certain amount of space *around* the given arrow, up to a maximum volume limited by both the size of the conductor and the amount of current.

Comment: By general, to what extent is the general? Assume that I was 10A, 10A will flow in that direction?

Comment: The charges will flow from one connection to the other. They will not flow in a straight line in single file.

Comment: If one we're to apply Lorentz force(if placed in a magnetic field), this direction of current as diagrammed is considered correct? So that the force would be perpendicular to it, acting at an angle?

Comment: as diagramed: http://i.imgur.com/KIKzG5V.png?1 and http://i.imgur.com/a8myJWK.png?1 is current flow and F considered valid?